Obtaining unrealistically high values for slice energy of a crystal plane
I am trying to calculate the slab energy of the basal plane of an ice crystal. This energy is defined as 'the energy released when a slab of thickness d_hkl is formed', and is calculated by summing up the intermolecular interactions of a central reference molecule in the slab with all of the other molecules present in the slab. For some reason, my code returns unrealistically high values for this energy (around 100 kJ/mol), and also returns a different energy depending on how many unit cells I place in the x- and y-direction (to simulate the bulk)
Calculating forces
To calculate the forces I use the TIP4P/ice model that places an extra site 'M' on the symmetry axis between the 'H' atoms and under the 'O' atom. This 'M' site contains the charge that was originally on the 'O' atom. A 6-12 Lennard-Jones potential is used to calculate the Van der Waals forces between the 'O' atoms, and the Coulombic forces are calculated between the two 'H' atoms and the 'M' site of the central molecule and the other molecule.
My code
This is what I've written down so far. I can't figure out why the Coulombic energy is so high and changing with the size of the supercell.
from ase.io import read, write
from ase.build import make_supercell, surface
from ase.visualize import view
from ase import Atoms
from ase.neighborlist import NeighborList
import numpy


Na = 6.022e23  # Avogadro [mol-1]
e_elem = 1.602e-19  # Elementary charge [C]
k_B = 1.38e-23  # Boltzmann constant [J/K]
epsilon = 106.1 * k_B  # [J]
sigma = 3.1668  # [AA]
r_cut= 2.5*sigma
planck_cte = 6.626e-34  # [Js] Planck constant
q_M = -1.1794 * e_elem  # Charge of M site [C]
q_H1 = 0.5897 * e_elem  # Charge of H site [C]
q_H2 = q_H1  # Charge of H site [C] ( same as previous but for clarity later on)
epsilon_naught = 8.8542e-12  # [F/m] or [C^2/(J m)]
k_el = 10**10/(4 * numpy.pi * epsilon_naught)  # First term of the C. potential  [J AA / C^2 ]
T=268
tolerance = 0.01
# Create supercells of slabs
# Create supercells of slabs
ice_structure = read(r"C:\Users\miepv\Documents\Master\Master\Thesis\Crystalgrower\CIF files\ice_crystal.cif")
#  view(ice_structure)
#  Cell parameters


miller_indices = {
    'basal': (0, 0, 1),
    'primary_prism': (1, 0, 0),
    'secondary_prism': (1, 1, 0),
    'pyramidal': (2, 0, 1)
}
slices = {
    'basal': [[8 ,0, 0], [0, 8, 0], [0, 0, 1]],
    'primary_prism': [[1, 0, 0], [0, 6, 0], [0, 0, 6]],
    'secondary_prism': ([[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 6]]),
    'pyramidal': ([[2, 0, 0], [0, 6, 0], [0, 0, 1]])
}
standard_supercell = make_supercell(ice_structure, [[8, 0, 0], [0,8, 0], [0, 0,8]])

slice_supercells = {}
for plane_name, slice_matrix in slices.items():
    slice_supercells[plane_name] = make_supercell(ice_structure, slice_matrix)

slabs = {}
for plane_name, supercell in slice_supercells.items():
    # Get the corresponding Miller index
    indices = miller_indices[plane_name]
    current_slab = surface(supercell, indices, layers=1)
    slabs[plane_name] = current_slab
#view(slabs['basal'])
molecules_basal = {}

for atom in slabs['basal']:
    if atom.symbol == 'O':
        pos_O = atom.position

        H_atoms = []
        for neighbor in slabs['basal']:
            if neighbor.symbol == 'H':
                distance = slabs['basal'].get_distance(atom.index, neighbor.index)
                if distance < 0.96:
                    H_atoms.append(neighbor.position)

            # Check if we have exactly 2 H atoms
        if len(H_atoms) == 2:
            pos_H1 = H_atoms[0]
            pos_H2 = H_atoms[1]

            # Calculate the pos of M atom
            pos_MP = [(pos_H1[0] + pos_H2[0]) / 2,
                      (pos_H1[1] + pos_H2[1]) / 2,
                      (pos_H1[2] + pos_H2[2]) / 2]
            direction = [pos_MP[0] - pos_O[0], pos_MP[1] - pos_O[1],
                         pos_MP[2] - pos_O[2]]
            norm_direction = numpy.linalg.norm(direction)

            pos_M = pos_O + 0.15 * norm_direction

            # Create a unique identifier for the molecule, e.g., using the O atom's pos
            molecule_id = f'molecule_{len(molecules_basal) + 1}'

            # Store the poss in the dictionary
            molecules_basal[molecule_id] = {
                'O': pos_O,
                'H1': pos_H1,
                'H2': pos_H2,
                'M': pos_M
            }

#central_x = 14.337
#central_y = 24.832
#central_z = 3.220

central_x = 16.944
central_y = 33.862
central_z = 4.140
tolerance = 0.001
for molecule_id, positions in molecules_basal.items():
    pos_O = positions['O']  # Get the position of O
    if (abs(pos_O[0] - central_x) < tolerance) and (abs(pos_O[1] - central_y) < tolerance) and (abs(pos_O[2] - central_z) < tolerance):
        central_molecule_id = molecule_id

ref_pos = molecules_basal[central_molecule_id]
pos_O_ref = ref_pos['O']
pos_H1_ref = ref_pos['H1']
pos_H2_ref = ref_pos['H2']
pos_M_ref = ref_pos['M']

E_slice = 0

for molecule_id, positions in molecules_basal.items():
    if molecule_id != central_molecule_id:
        pos_O = positions['O']
        pos_H1 = positions['H1']
        pos_H2 = positions['H2']
        pos_M = positions['M']

# Calculate the LJ potential for the E between the O-atoms
        r_OO = numpy.linalg.norm(pos_O_ref - pos_O)  # [AA]
        U_LJ = 4 * epsilon * (pow((sigma / r_OO), 12) - pow((sigma / r_OO), 6))  # [J]
        # Calculate the electric potential between the charges (M,H)
        r_H1_H1 = numpy.linalg.norm(pos_H1_ref - pos_H1)  # [AA]
        r_H1_H2 = numpy.linalg.norm(pos_H1_ref - pos_H2)
        r_H1_M = numpy.linalg.norm(pos_H1_ref - pos_M)

        r_H2_H1 = numpy.linalg.norm(pos_H2_ref - pos_H1)
        r_H2_H2 = numpy.linalg.norm(pos_H2_ref - pos_H2)
        r_H2_M = numpy.linalg.norm(pos_H2_ref - pos_M)

        r_M_H1 = numpy.linalg.norm(pos_M_ref - pos_H1)
        r_M_H2 = numpy.linalg.norm(pos_M_ref - pos_H2)
        r_M_M = numpy.linalg.norm(pos_M_ref - pos_M)
# Calculate the Coulombic potential
        U_C = k_el * ((q_H1 * q_H1 / r_H1_H1) + (q_H1 * q_H2 / r_H1_H2) + (q_H1 * q_M / r_H1_M)
                          + (q_H2 * q_H1 / r_H2_H1) + (q_H2 * q_H2 / r_H2_H2) + (q_H2 * q_M / r_H2_M)
                          + (q_M * q_H1 / r_M_H1) + (q_M * q_H2 / r_M_H2) + (q_M * q_M / r_M_M))
        print(U_LJ)
        E_slice += U_C + U_LJ  # in [J]

